# Why doesn't $E$ depend on $x$?

Tags: electrostatics

Suppose that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the infinite yz-plane is charged with a superficial charge density of $\sigma$. Then I have calculated that the electric field is equal to $E=sgn(x)\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}e_x$, which agrees with the solution of my professor. But how can it be that the absolute value doesn't depend on $x$? Wouldn't a force of a charge $q$ at $(1000,0,0)$ be way smaller than on the same charge $q$ at $(1,0,0)$?

I have no clue on how to argue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your plane is infinite. This means it doesn't matter how far away you are from it, you can always think as if you were too close.

Comment: Anther great example of why one should not use infinite models in physics, period. You professor needs to man up and teach real physics rather than mathematical toy models without any physics content.

Comment: @CuriousOne As i am interested to learn the "right" way, could you please tell me in which branch of mathematics should i refer to in order to properly learn how to model such problems in the right way?

Comment: @QuanticMan: It's not a problem of mathematics, it's a problem of poor physics teaching. Absolutely nothing stops a professor from explaining how one treats a finite plate correctly. Most classes, however, don't do that, so you end up with students who can't calculate any EM problem that doesn't include either a trivially symmetric structure like a sphere or an infinite plane. In reality we never have to deal with either.

Comment: @CuriousOne So how can a student deal with that and learn in the right way himself?

Comment: @QuanticMan: Strangely enough you may have to look at the engineering literature of the early to mid 20th-century, I am afraid, where engineers and physicists who had to deal with real, finite EM problems have done this right because they couldn't afford to do it wrong and easy.  To this day even highly praised physics textbooks are full of un-physical infinite geometries. To me that's a very questionable development.

Comment: @CuriousOne I understand. Also, and please correct me if I am wrong at this but, as I understand it you are suggesting that using our "intuition" involving infinities in order to make a problem easier is not the right way, right? So, we have got to use mathematics(here vector analysis, i think) in order to solve the problems correctly. Please, excuse me if I am wrong, as I have only taken introductory physics courses so far.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you are looking through a telescope that zooms in and only lets you see a very small region of the plane. Let's think about what happens to the electric field from the area you are looking at as you move the plane away from you, while you keep the direction of your telescope fixed. If you double your distance from the plane two things happen, and these two things offset each other.

1) The charge that you see gets farther away, so the strength of field per unit charge you see decreases by a factor of four.

2) At the same time, you will see four times the area of the sheet, so you will see four times the amount of charge.

Since you have one fourth the electric field per unit charge, but four times the charge, the electric field from the region that can be seen through your telescope does not change as the sheet is moved.

Since the total electric field is just the sum over the electric field you can see through your telescope as you scan your telescope over the sheet, the total electric field does not change.

Mathematically, you would say the electric field you are looking at $d\mathbf{E}$ is given by $$d\mathbf{E}=\frac{dq}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{r^2 \sigma d\Omega/\cos \theta}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{ \sigma d\Omega/\cos \theta}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$. We can see already that the $r$ dependence has dropped out, so $d\mathbf{E}$ does not depend on the distance from the sheet. Taking the $z$ component, we get $$d E_z=\frac{ \sigma d\Omega/\cos \theta}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cos \theta=\frac{ \sigma d\Omega}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} $$. The integrand is constant. Since the total solid angle that $d\Omega$ ranges over is a half sphere, the total solid angle $\Omega$ is $2 \pi$ and we find $$E_z=\frac{ \sigma \Omega}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}= \frac{ \sigma }{2 \epsilon_0}$$

Comment: Great explanation(you and the explanation below), but i have one thing that concerns me: My answer is about symmetry and the infinity of the dimensions of the plane while your answer has to do with symmetry and the strength of the E-field. So, i wonder which one is correct. Both seem reasonable. So, if we have a non-uniform charge density but it linearly grows (for example) as we get far away from (0,0,0) in the yz plane, then what we would get?

Comment: Now, symmetry is preserved, but now, the argument about the E-field does not stand. So, if in this case, the E-filed above (0,0,0) is dependent of x, then your answer is correct, otherwise mine is correct. Whatever it is, nice answer! Hope i didn't confuse you!

Comment: @QuanticMan I usually don't like to be negative, but your explanation is incomplete. As you say, it does depend on the charge density being uniform, not just on the radial symmetry of the charge distribution. Also, even if you were to assume a completely uniform charge distribution, your argument is still incomplete, because it goes through for other force laws besides $1/r^2$. However, the $1/r^2$ law is a crucial ingredient here, so any complete explanation as to why the electric field is uniform must reference the $1/r^2$ nature of the force law.

Comment: @QuanticMan I should add though that the explanation you gave is a very popular one (as we can see by the voting). I think it gets taught in freshman physics classes a lot, and there may be a good reason for that. I think it might be more intuitive or easy to understand.

Comment: I have only taken an introductory course in EM and QM. So, I really haven't got any practice with other force laws yet, so i haven't really thought of it this way. You are right and it's a great revelation to me! Nothing better for an amateur and young physicist in the making to learn that something he did was wrong because it give you a lesson that maybe something seems the most reasonable thing ever but it can still be wrong! Check my edited answer in a minute! :)

Answer (score 2):

The detailed answer by NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs (and Andrea) is the correct one and I will leave my answer as it is so it can be viewed by other users who might have thought of this themselves in order to understand the **fundamental mistake** they make. This answer Implies that this goes for any kind of force field with a source of similar geometry, while the truth is that the independence of x is due to the *$\frac{1}{r^2}$* law.

*Original Answer:*

**A pedestrian, but i think intuitive explanation:**
You have to let your imagination go a bit wild here and start thinking about the effects that something infinite can have in your calculations. You have an infinite sheet that is charged. No matter how far from that sheet you go, you will still "see" an infinite sheet. It is something that never ends, symmetric in every direction on the *yz* plane. No matter how close you come to the sheet, you will still "see" the same things that you "see" when you go very very far.

**A Small Extra:**
The infinite dimensions of the plane are also the reason that your E-field has its only component in the x-direction. If your plane had finite dimensions, and say it was circular(to preserve some of the symmetry of your problem), then you would have an E-filed pointing only in the x direction for all the points above the center of that circle. Now, let the radius of that circle tend to infinity. Then, the magic happens! No matter where you are, your E-fields always points to the x-direction. You are always in the middle of that infinite circle in a way!
But, be careful, not all the problems concerning a geometry of an object of some dimension being infinite have E or B-fields independent of the distance from the source(s). So, don't follow my kind of thinking for this problem blindly, because it will mess you up(check infinite line of uniform change density problem).

**Advise:**
If you have a problem conceptualizing this, then you should do more exercises of similar structure, just to get a feeling of what this kind of infinity "does to physics".

Comment: Infinity doesn't do anything to physics because it doesn't exist. What does exist are teachers who are too lazy to teach how we approximate multivariate functions in the near and the far field properly and what the limit behavior of physical systems under scale operations is.

Comment: @CuriousOne but as i said, this answer is meant to just conceptualize the stuff. It is not rigorous, nor precise. If the OP can "visualize" what the "really big" dimensions of the plane mean, then I think it will help his intuition. That is the logic behind my original answer, anyway.

Comment: You can't "conceptualize stuff" by avoiding its difficulties by replacing it with other "stuff" that doesn't exist. It's not just not rigorous, it's outright false, as you will soon discover when you move from this example to that of infinite solenoids and dipoles. When you do non-equivalence operations in mathematics (like in this case), you sometimes get the correct answer and you sometimes do not, but you are not guaranteed to get the right answer all the time unless you do it right, all the time. All the fuzzy-wuzzy waving with infinite models breaks down past the trivial examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this clear [answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-the-electric-field-of-an-infinitely-large-plane-depend-on-the-distance-from-the-plane) to your question: I mean Raziman T.V.'s explanation. Enjoy it!

Here's the answer:

> Feynman explains this well in his lectures (Chapter 13 : Work and
>   Potential energy (A)). The explanation is for the gravitational field
>   of a plane, but the same argument works for the electric field of a
>   charged sheet as well.
>
> The essential idea is this : When you come closer to the plane, the
>   magnitude of of the field due to every infinitesimal piece of the
>   plane is large. But since field is a vector, its direction is
>   important too. When you are close to the surface, the field
>   contributions from most of the parts of the plane are almost parallel
>   to the surface, and all parallel contributions cancel off because of
>   symmetry. As you move away from the surface, though the magnitudes of
>   the individual field contributions are reduced, the field
>   contributions start becoming more and more perpendicular to the plane
>   and there is no symmetry-based cancellation for the perpendicular
>   component. The force being inverse squared means that the two effects
>   will nullify each other perfectly and the field remains constant.